# Canviz example don't work

Tags: javascript, graphviz

I've downloaded Canviz (it's a Javascript library for drawing graphs). I've unzipped the archive. I open, with Chrome, index.html, which is supposed to be an example. A "loading" message appears... and never disappears.

What am I supposed to do please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked with this library a few months ago.

You also need to have graphviz installed in order to create the graphs canviz will draw.

When you have installed, you have to use the function load with the url parameters in order to create the graph.

Answer (score -1):

WebBrowsers have an option to enable javascript or not. make sure your browser enable it.

here's an example for Mozilla : [Mozilla example](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/javascript-settings-for-interactive-web-pages)

Comment: Yes, my browser enable it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11671329)

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand This is not a link only answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver it is, only a link is provided here where an explanation could also be included directly in the answer.

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand So *WebBrowsers have an option to enable javascript or not. make sure your browser enable it.* doesn't qualify as an attempt to answer?  See: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Comment: @NathanOliver so the sentence you quoted is the "essential part of the answer"? - IMO, if the link dies, all this tells you is that you can enable and disable JS in your browser. I still wouldn't know if JS is actually enabled or disabled in the first place, I think that what you quoted could as well be a comment as it is a possibility but it's highly unlikely to solve the issue (probably missing file / JS error somewhere). Also seeing that the user that posted this question doesn't have sufficient rep to comment.